# Woocommerce Force Download on Order Received Page

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, ftp

I am developing a Wordpress site that uses the WooCommerce shopping cart and Paypal to sell digital products (the site is not yet live).

I want the digital product to be automatically downloaded to the customers browser on their Order Received page. The Order Received page confirms the Paypal order on my Wordpress site.

Hopefully I can lower the risk of sharing the download location by sending the file to the customer and hiding the url rather than having a download location which is public. The first question is do you have a PHP snippet that can be used possibly in the functions.php file of my child theme to force the download of the product?

Secondly, the WooCommerce Order Received page doesn't appear in the Wordpress pages section, what is the location of the file for editing? I see order-details.php in woocommerce\templates\order\ but not sure if that is correct.

Comment: Yes, `order-details.php` has a summary of the purchase just made.

Comment: As mentioned already, WooCommerce will do all of this for you.  For a better PayPal experience in general, though, I'd recommend using our [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) plugin with Express Checkout.